# Recursive lambdas in Ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion, lambda

I have the following code which correctly generates all possible trees of size `num`:

```
class Tree
  attr_accessor :left, :right

  def initialize left = nil, right = nil
    @left = left
    @right = right
  end

  # Don't ever specify any arguments, it will make me very angry.
  # Tilt your head 90 degrees to the side to see the tree when viewing.
  def print level = 0
    @right.pretty_print(level + 1) if @right
    puts ('  ' * level) + to_s
    @left.pretty_print(level + 1) if @left
  end

  def self.generate num
    trees = []
    generate_subtrees(num) { |tree| trees << tree } if num > 0
    trees
  end

  private

  def self.generate_subtrees num, &block
    if num == 0
      yield nil
    else
      (1..num).each do |root_position|
        generate_subtrees(root_position - 1) do |left|
          generate_subtrees(num - root_position) do |right|
            yield Tree.new nil, left, right
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I’m trying to (for the sake of it) “condense” this into one method, utilizing lambda recursion. My current attempt (of several iterations) is below:

```
def self.generate num
  trees = []

  gen = ->(num, &block) do
    if num == 0
      yield nil                                       # L61
    else
      (1..num).each do |root_position|                # L63
        gen.call(root_position - 1) do |left|         # L64
          gen.call(num - root_position) do |right|
            block.call { Tree.new nil, left, right }
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  gen.call(num) { |tree| trees << tree }              # L73

  trees
end
```

This results in the error (referenced lines noted above):

```
LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
    from tree.rb:61:in `block in generate'
    from tree.rb:64:in `call'
    from tree.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in generate'
    from tree.rb:63:in `each'
    from tree.rb:63:in `block in generate'
    from tree.rb:73:in `call'
    from tree.rb:73:in `generate'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/amarshall/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong? Alternative solutions to this mostly academic problem are also welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Dave! Could never spell lambdas quite right…

Comment: You should post some minimal code for the Tree class so we can easily test new versions of this function.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I've posted more of the Tree class as requested (though not all of it, let me know if there are any errors with my minimization).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `yield` keyword does not work from inside a lambda. The alternative is to use `&block`, in the same way that you are already doing on line 64 and 65:

```
gen = ->(num, &block) do
if num == 0
  block.call(nil)
else
  # ...
end

gen.call(num) { |tree| trees << tree }
```

Comment: I swear I had changed that one (at least at some point I probably did but had a combination of other things wrong). Also, this pointed out the on line 66 I should've been using parenthesis instead of curly brackets. Thanks!